Voltage and current excitation in diffusion equation
Dear Physics community,
i am having trouble with the diffusion equation and the Maxwell equations. I am investigating a system where a voltage is the source of eddy currents. However, most established works utilize either the current or the flux density distribution for the calculation of eddy current losses.
With current densities or a flux density distribution governing PDE is quite straight forward:
$$  
-\frac{1}{\mu} \nabla^2 \vec{A} +\kappa\frac{d\vec{A}}{dt} = \vec{J}_{ext} 
$$
Where J_ext(x,y,z,t) is the current on a boundary e.g. the boundary of the calculation domain.
I can solve this with a Fourier transform.
if i want to use a voltage, therefore an electric field at the boundary
$$\vec{J} = \kappa\vec{E}+\vec{J}_{int} = \kappa\vec{E}-\kappa \frac{d\vec{A}}{dt}$$
With the conductivity kappa. When utilizing the vector identity and the coulomb gauge the PDE is
$$ \frac{1}{\mu} ( -\nabla^2 \vec{A}) +\kappa \frac{d\vec{A}}{dt} = \kappa\vec{E} $$
Therefore the results are the same for both, the external current density and a case where i calculate the currents based on a electrostatic electric field.
This however is not a physically correct case. Because of the changing magnetic fields the current in the case where the electric voltage is source of the excitation the current should be lower than the resistivity limited case due to induced voltages based on changing magnetic fields. Now either the first PDE is unable to imprint the currents on the boundary and a superposition of internal and external currents is taking place, or the second PDE is for some reason not the physical case.
Could anyone explain what is going on ?
Thank you.
